# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'int' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, list, dart

> Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'int' which excludes null. _countries.indexWhere((country)

```
onTap: () {
    int index =
        _countries.indexWhere((country) {
              return country.startsWith(
                  alphabet.toUpperCase());
            }) ??
            0;
    _listController.jumpTo(
      index * 60.0,
    );
  },
  child: Text(
    alphabet,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: _theme.primaryColor,
      fontSize: 14.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html), `List.indexWhere` always returns `int` - if the element isn't found, the return value is -1, but you seem to be thinking that it's `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) on `indexWhere` clearly states:

> Returns -1 if element is not found.

So there is no possible way that your call returns `null`. The `??` operator only works on a nullable variable/expression, because it will return the result, or (in your case) `0` if the result is `null`. The result can never be `null` so your compiler tells you that that statement does not make any sense.

If you wanted the `-1` to also be `0`, you could use `min` to make sure the minimum you get is always `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`indexWhere` doesn't return nullable int. You might want `firstWhere` and then find index.

```dart
String item = _countries.firstWhere((country) {
    return country.startsWith(alphabet.toUpperCase());
  }, orElse: () => _countries.first);

  int index = _countries.indexWhere((element) => element == item);
```

```dart
int selectedIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _countries.length; i++) {
  if (_countries[i].startsWith(alphabet.toUpperCase())) {
    selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

I hope there are better ways of doing it.